# What does this math notation mean? $\min_{i} \|x_{i}\|$

Tags: statistics, notation, machine-learning

$\qquad\min_{i} \|x_{i}\|$

I'm doing some machine learning problems and I ran into this notation.

I don't understand what "**min<sub>i</sub>**" means in this case.

Is it the smallest element in the norm of $x$? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $\min_ix_i=\min\{x_i \mid i\in I\}$, in general.

Comment: It means "minimum of all $||x_i||$ across all the values of the index $i$". Which values the index $i$ can take is not specified in the notation but should be clear from the context. There are alternative notations which can specify the range of $i$ as well, such as $\min_{i\in I}||x_i||$ or $\min_{1\le i\le n}||x_i||$ etc.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Now is $I$ just refering to some set of indices?

Comment: Yup, pretty much. If you're just given $i$ and not a specific indexing set, the indexing set is meant to be implied or understood from the more general context, or taken as all relevant values.

Comment: It's been only 30 minutes, but this question has been downvoted already. I don't understand that. A new user has asked a genuine question, in good english and he clearly asked what he wanted to know in an understandable way. I thought downvotes were only vor questions that were stated very unclearly. I think people should ignore question that they consider not interesting, instead of just downright downvoting and potentially scaring off new users. Sorry for being off-topic, i provided an answer to the question, along with the other people who commented, i hope it was helpful!

Comment: Thank you guys.

Answer (score 3):

$\min_{i}\Vert x_{i}\Vert$ is a sloppy shorthand notation for the smallest norm (i assume || denotes a norm, otherwise some sort of absolute value) of each of the $x_i$. For example if you have $3$ elements $x_1, x_2$ and $x_3$ with norms $\Vert x_1\Vert = 5$, $\Vert x_2\Vert = 8$ and $\Vert x_3\Vert = 2$, then

\begin{align*}
\min_{i}\Vert x_{i}\Vert = \Vert x_3\Vert = 2
\end{align*}

As has already been pointed out in the comments, more formally $i$ ranges over all elements in some index set $I$, i.e.
\begin{align*}
\min_{i}\Vert x_{i}\Vert = \min\{\Vert x_{i}\Vert, \, i\in I\}.
\end{align*}
In the example I gave, one could have had $I = \{1, 2, 3\}$ as index set, as there were $3$ elements of which the minimum norm was chosen.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you very much.

Comment: No problem, i hope it helped! I upvoted your question, it did not deserve that downvote by somebody, welcome on math.stackexchange!